# Ubuntu Server upgrade over SSH hang

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I was upgrading an Ubuntu server (using the do-release-upgrade) command over SSH (I know it's a bad idea, but it was the only choice; I don't have physical access to the server). It seemed to go fine and was going thru the 'setting up *package name*' part when it froze on the line

```
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/debian-start ...
```

The SSH connection appears to be still active, as pressing the up arrow echoes back ^[[A, and so on. When I log in on another SSH connection I can log in fine, but the ** system needs restart ** message shows up. Is it safe to ^C the release-upgrade command, or try to reboot the server? Should I ^C the upgrade and try it again? Anything else I could try?

Comment: General advice; Start the upgrade inside a screen next time.  At least that way you can reattach to the session if it's the ssh-connection that messes up.

Comment: do-release-upgrade already starts itself in a screen session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reattach to Ubuntu Server's 'do-release-upgrade' process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/387547/how-do-i-reattach-to-ubuntu-servers-do-release-upgrade-process)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually do release upgrades over VPN, so I've tried this a few times. Whenever it updates my openvpn package I lose connection, so I reconnect afterwards.

`do-release-upgrade` starts a backup SSH session on port 1022 and a backup screen session. If you do not have screen installed this will NOT be available.

You can get the screen session by running:

```
sudo screen -list
There is a screen on:
    2953.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window   (09/13/2012 04:48:02 AM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

Then to reattach do:

```
sudo screen -d -r root/2953.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window
```

Using the previously listed screen after `root/`

You should be back to where you lost connection.

Comment: this is the best and safest solution, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

I got nervous when this happened to me today. It froze for about 15 minutes.

Trying to solve this, I got a second SSH connection running, found mysql PIDs via `ps aux | grep mysql` and killed them. It didn't seem to help, so I used `service mysql stop` - thankfully **it worked** and after a few seconds do-release-upgrade did its remaining job.

That was close. No more upgrades for tonight :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the exact same problem.

I'm not sure if it's a fix, or the right way of going about it....

but I `Ctrl+C` the process, then.

`sudo rm  /var/lib/dpkg/lock`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` (you'll probably get some errors)
`sudo apt-get remove mysql-server`  # we can fix this later.  I'm mainly concerned 
with getting the OS to boot properly

Once that was complete, I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`

I think I'll end up having to do the `dpkg --configure -a` and `dist-upgrade` several times before all the bugs get ironed out.

Not perfect, and messy.. but a suggestion?

Comment: Great thanks! I ctrl-C'd it and did dpkg-configure -a, rebooted and it seems to be ok!  my hang was pretty late into the upgrade so it was almost finished, so I guess you'd have more bugs, or totally kill the system, if it happened earlier. From what I saw after ctrl-C, the actual do-release-upgrade hung, not the ssh session. Anyway thanks for the help! Lifesaver!